# Looking for data in Smart contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, solidity-0.6.x, function

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.3;

contract Storage {
    struct People {
        uint256 personId;
        string vorname;
        string nachname;
        uint256 birthdate;
    }

    struct Decision {
        string decision;
        string wantdonate;
        string dontwantdonate;
    }

    People[] public people;
    mapping(string => Decision) internal vornameToDonation;
    mapping(string => mapping(string => Decision)) internal nachnameToDonation;
    mapping(uint256 => mapping(string => mapping(string => Decision)))
        public birthdayToDonation;

    address public owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        if (msg.sender != owner) {
            revert("NotOwnerError");
        }
        _;
    }

    uint256 public peopleCount = 0;

    function addPerson(
        uint256 _birthdate,
        string memory _vorname,
        string memory _nachname,
        string memory _decision,
        string memory _wantdonate,
        string memory _dontwantdonate
    ) public onlyOwner {
        people.push(People(peopleCount, _vorname, _nachname, _birthdate));
        birthdayToDonation[_birthdate][_nachname][_vorname] = Decision(
            _decision,
            _wantdonate,
            _dontwantdonate
        );
        peopleCount++;
    }

    function readDonation(
        uint256 _birthdate,
        string memory _vorname,
        string memory _nachname
    ) public view onlyOwner returns (Decision memory) {
        Decision memory readOnly = vornameToDonation[type(Storage).name];

        return readOnly;
    }

    function removePerson(uint256 index) external onlyOwner {
        //if (index >= people.length) return revert('Person does not exist!');
        if (index == people[index].personId) delete people[index];
        peopleCount--;
    }
}
```

With my function readDonation i want to look for people i added with my function addPeople. I used this extra function because i want to make sure that only the owner of the contract can look for people. But i found no possibility to tip in the first name, last name and the birthdate and then get the answer for donation, wantdonate and dontwantdonate. Also i want to look for this with the mapping. Can somebody give me an idea or approach for make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you can't restrict reads to your smart contract.
The information is readable by anyone, so even if your read function is `onlyOwner`, anyone with enough skill can access your `vornameToDonation` mapping.

Your solutions are to either encrypt that information (You'll still have GDPR problems) or keep it off chain.

Also, your function `addPerson()` or any function in your code, adds anything to the `vornameToDonation` mapping

Best of luck!